# Query objects NOT within a certain distance

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm using Parse in my app. I want to be able to query objects that are not within 100 km from the user's location. I'm aware of the function whereKey:nearGeopoint:withinKilometers however it doesn't do what I want. I can fix that by calculating the distance of the user and the object returned and add the wanted objects inside an array, however what if the returned objects (query has a limit of 10 objects to return) are all within the 100km or out of 10, 9 are within the distance? i have to re-query again. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using a CloudCode Function ([Link](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions)) would be the best approach. Iterate through the table until you get 10 geopoints that are at least 100km away from the user's position.